# Looking for Tomcat6 customisation on Cloudbees to add 3rd party jars

Tags: maven, tomcat6, cloudbees

I have been searching in the documentation for [Clickstack](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack) and on [the Cloudbees Community Github](https://github.com/CloudBees-community) to create a custom container. There is a standard template for apps and one project for Tomcat7 but none forking the Cloudbees default Tomcat6. 
I would like to add some dependencies into the Tomcat6 container instead of bundling them in the application WAR.
For example, an application could have AWS sdk as provided in pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

this seems simple. However (in my little understanding of things) do I need to develop the container from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tomcat6 one has a long history - and is called "staxcat"

https://github.com/CloudBees-community/staxcat-clickstack

You can certainly fork and base it off that. The approach with tomcat7 was to have a less customised stack - closer to vanilla tomcat7.

My recommendation is to use tomcat7 as a starting point - if you can at all (tomcat6 is becoming a tad old now!)- but if you really need tomcat6, staxcat might be the repo to look at!